# Concatenate in SQL or programatically in Java or etc

Tags: java, sql

Maybe this is an opinion based question, but I couldn't find a better place to ask

So I have a query like this,

```
SELECT A.f1, B.f2 
FROM TABLEA A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEB B
```

So B.f2 can be null if the the outer join gets nothing.

So I got 2 approches, should I concatenate in SQL

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN (B.f2 IS NULL)
THEN A.f1
ELSE A.f1 + ' ' + B.f2
.....
```

or should I do that programatically

```
String Af1 = resultSet.getString(Af1);
String Bf2 = resultSet.getString(Bf2);
if(Bf2 == null)
   return Af1
else
   return Af1 + " " + Bf2
```

Comment: I want to know what gives me better performance..

Comment: I think you should do this in sql, sql concatenate strings should not be much more expensive than in java, but you will have one column less to transport across network and read in your java code.